# Free Syntax Highlighting .NET Editor

Tags: .net, winforms, wpf-controls, editor

I need incorporate a syntax highlighting editor control into my application. It is required that the control be free and native .NET code only so the Scintilla.NET control is not feasible. The reason for this is because it is a ClickOnce application.

I would like answers that use WinForms or WPF. It doesn't have to be from the same vendor. It needs to basically support syntax highlighting, line numbers, and be reasonably fast for large files up to 100,000 and MUST be FREE!

I understand that this question has been asked before for they are usually muddled with commercial controls that require royalties or are not free or mention the Scintilla.NET control which is not native .NET code.

Comment: I have searched for this so many times, never have found one, so I hope you get a good answer to this question ;)

Comment: There's one that does not fit your requirements: The Visual Studio Shell. (See the examples on MSDN.) It is basically free but cannot be distributed as a component nor using ClickOnce. You can do syntax highlighting and a lot more though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to see if the text control that was built for MonoDevelop 2 will help you out.  Its integrated, and you'll need to see if the licensing suits you.

It does use GTK+, though, so you'd likely need to have the GtkSharp wrapper around GTK+.  But it would be possible in theory to use it as a basis for something that sits on top of the GUI API system you're programming for.

**ETA**:  You may also want to check out the code used in SharpDevelop, which runs on Windows.  There are programmers in common between the two projects, as well.

Links:
     [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page)

Comment: Maybe the text control for SharpDevelop would work, then? I recall the author of Kaxaml saying that he used that control.

Comment: That is certainly a possibility.  I can edit my comment to include mention of that for sure.

Comment: MonoDevelop was forked from SharpDevelop some time ago (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop). Both are open source, but SharpDevelop is more suited to integration with WinForms apps because it's not tied to GTK+.

Comment: These solutions are fairly good. I'm looking for a user control now the actual IDE itself. I understand that SharpDevelop has a user control that is an editor. It's number one on my list for now but are there any other options available?

Comment: I have tried SharpDevelop editor, it is fair good however it is based on WPF.

Answer (score 13):

The SharpDevelop IDE is an open source Visual Studio alternative, and its editor provides syntax colouring and autocomplete for C# and other languages. The editor control can be used separately from the rest of the IDE, and there's an example in the samples that shows how you can integrate it into your own solution (samples\CSharpCodeCompletion I think).

Try the community forums if you have any difficulties:

http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/

It's written in C# and WinForms.