# Are there any free code editor WinForms controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono, text-editor

I'm searching for a free text/code editor **WinForms control** just like [ScintillaNET](http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET).

I cannot use ScintillaNET, because it doesn't support Mono.

Ideally it should be a pure managed control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't sharpdevelop have a control? Or monodevelop?  Can you get their source and see if you can use a control from there? 
Or would this work?  [Fireedit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScriptEditorCtrl.aspx) from Code project.
Or [this](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/aspnet/codehighlighter/default.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Sharp Develop?

I think its open source so you can get the text editor they created...

[EDIT]

See this post:
[Free Syntax Highlighting .NET Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619807/free-syntax-highlighting-net-editor)

And, as a further help - SharpDevelop 4.0 uses AvalonEdit as the Syntax highlighting editor:

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx

how to use AvalonEdit:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx

Comment: AvalonEdit is WPF. Mono doesn't support WPF.